# Return code always 0 for running parallel Alteryx workflows in Python using Subprocess

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, alteryx

Am trying to run few Alteryx workflows in Python in parallel using Subprocess. Here is the script.

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

workflows =["C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\Sample2.yxmd","C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\Sample.yxmd"]

processes = []
for file in workflows:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\AppData\\Local\\Alteryx\\bin\\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe", file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    processes.append(p)
    print(processes)
    
for i in processes:
    while i.poll() is None:
        # Process hasn't exited yet, let's wait some
        time.sleep(0.5)
    

res = processes[0].communicate()
print("return code =", processes[0].returncode)
print("stderr =", res[1])

res2 = processes[1].communicate()
print("return code =", processes[1].returncode)
print("stderr =", res2[1])
```

It completes to run the code, however it does not give out the right return code**(it is always 0)** even though i induced an error in one of the workflow to debug the code.

However when i run the same workflows sequentially, they give the right return codes to notify error, here is the script

```
workflow1 = "C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\Sample 2.yxmd"
subprocess.run(["C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\AppData\\Local\\Alteryx\\bin\\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe", workflow1])
```

Output - Return code =0 # Signifying error(this is the workflow i deliberately created error)

```
 workflow2 = "C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\Sample.yxmd"  


subprocess.run(["C:\\Users\\vevek.seetharaman\\AppData\\Local\\Alteryx\\bin\\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe", workflow2])
```

Output - Return code = 1 # Signifying success

PS: Apologies that am not able to give you a working code as i had to point to a location using code

Comment: Could it be that, while your workflow had an error, Alteryx handled it gracefully so that from the subprocess' perspective, everything ran nicely?

Comment: I doubt it, when i ran the same workflow sequentially using subprocess.run, it returns with an error code. Updating the question to reflect this observation

Comment: What if you run the same `p = subprocess.Popen` command sequentially and capture both stdout and stderr in the same fashion as done in the loop, then assess `p.return code`... is it still always zero? You may need to check stderr to see if anything's there, in order to detetmine success or failure.

Comment: still same result. i feel am missing out on something